# JSONObject etc instantiation crashing

Tags: java, json

I am trying to learn how to use JSON and writing a simple program however whenever I instantiate a JSON Object it crashes.
What am I missing if I receive this error when trying to instantiate a JSONObject or JSONArray. I have added http://sourceforge.net/projects/json-lib/files/ this JSON library to the build path. Is there anything I am missing?

The error message is as follows:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/lang/exception/NestableRuntimeException
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at jsonexp.JSONexp.<init>(JSONexp.java:36)
    at jsonexp.JSONexp.main(JSONexp.java:55)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.lang.exception.NestableRuntimeException
```

I have learned that this sort of error occurs when the library being used depends on another library.

I do not know how to deal with this problem and would very much appreciate some help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way to do this would be to use [findjar](http://findjar.com/index.x) to find the jar containing missing class for you and add it to you lib folder.

Comment: I wish I would have found this answer earlier, I had already ripped out all my hairs, put a gun in my mouth and was about to press the trigger. Thankfully, I found this and live to tell the story.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the jar you are including has it's own runtime dependencies that are not satisfied.

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.lang.exception.NestableRuntimeException

When seeing these type errors, I usually google around until I find the library responsible. This particular case it is the [Apache Commons Lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang/) library. Including this jar in your class path should solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

You're forgetting the jar that contains the class `NestableRuntimeException`.

Based on the package of that exception, it is an [Apache Commons](http://commons.apache.org/) library and you must go to [Apache Commons](http://commons.apache.org/) and download the [Apache Commons Lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang/) library. Download the [commons-lang-x.y-bin.(tar.gz|bin)](http://commons.apache.org/lang/download_lang.cgi) archive, get the jar from the archive and add it to your project or java classpath.