# SAP BO CMC - Error in Information Steward link on CMC (SBOP BI 4.1 sp5 & SBO EIM 4.2 sp3): Servlet execution threw an exception

Tags: java, servlets, servlet-filters, business-objects

I have installed SAP BusinessObjects.

Now I installed the app Information Steward but unfortunately something goes wrong!

At the end of the installation show up the following error:

> ```
> HTTP Status 500 - Servlet execution threw an exception
> type Exception report
> message Servlet execution threw an exception
> description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.
> exception 
> javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet execution threw an exception
> com.businessobjects.pinger.TimeoutManagerFilter.doFilter(TimeoutManagerFilter.java:168)
> root cause 
> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/fileupload/FileUpload
> org.apache.myfaces.webapp.filter.ExtensionsFilter.doFilter(ExtensionsFilter.java:114)
> com.businessobjects.http.servlet.internal.FilterRegistration.doFilter(FilterRegistration.java:72)
> com.businessobjects.http.servlet.internal.filter.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:43)
> com.businessobjects.mm.SessionTimeoutFilter.doFilter(SessionTimeoutFilter.java:86)
> com.businessobjects.http.servlet.internal.FilterRegistration.doFilter(FilterRegistration.java:72)
> com.businessobjects.http.servlet.internal.filter.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:43)
> com.businessobjects.mm.TraceLogScopeFilter.doFilter(TraceLogScopeFilter.java:35)
> com.businessobjects.http.servlet.internal.FilterRegistration.doFilter(FilterRegistration.java:72)
> com.businessobjects.http.servlet.internal.filter.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:43)
> com.businessobjects.bip.core.web.boetrustguard.BOETrustPrepareFilter.doFilter(BOETrustPrepareFilter.java:35)
> com.businessobjects.http.servlet.internal.FilterRegistration.doFilter(FilterRegistration.java:72)
> com.businessobjects.http.servlet.internal.filter.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:43)
> com.businessobjects.bip.core.web.supportabilty.TraceLogScopeFilter.doFilter(TraceLogScopeFilter.java:38)
> com.businessobjects.http.servlet.internal.FilterRegistration.doFilter(FilterRegistration.java:72)
> com.businessobjects.http.servlet.internal.filter.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:43)
> com.businessobjects.sdk.actionfilter.WorkflowFilter.doFilter(WorkflowFilter.java:45)
> com.businessobjects.http.servlet.internal.FilterRegistration.doFilter(FilterRegistration.java:72)
> com.businessobjects.http.servlet.internal.filter.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:43)
> com.businessobjects.bip.core.web.appcontext.RequestInitFilter.doFilter(RequestInitFilter.java:26)
> com.businessobjects.http.servlet.internal.FilterRegistration.doFilter(FilterRegistration.java:72)
> com.businessobjects.http.servlet.internal.filter.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:43)
> com.businessobjects.http.servlet.internal.BundlePathAwareServiceHandler.serviceHelper(BundlePathAwareServiceHandler.java:235)
> com.businessobjects.http.servlet.internal.BundlePathAwareServiceHandler.service(BundlePathAwareServiceHandler.java:197)
> com.businessobjects.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:248)
> javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
> org.eclipse.equinox.servletbridge.BridgeServlet.service(BridgeServlet.java:220)
> javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
> com.businessobjects.pinger.TimeoutManagerFilter.doFilter(TimeoutManagerFilter.java:168)
> note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.55 logs.
> --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
> Apache Tomcat/7.0.55
> ```

At SAP forum they do not know how fix it:

[SAP SCN](http://scn.sap.com/thread/3668812)

On Stack Overflow neither:

- [stack1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13639068/tomcat7-http-status-500-servlet-execution-threw-an-exception)
- [stack2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25615874/http-status-500-servlet-execution-threw-an-exception)

I do not think there is need of writing code, and I'm not sure if I have to add manually the missing class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Someone has posted an answer on the SCN thread OP linked to, which solved the problem:

> Marco -   Upgrade your Data Services/Information Steward applications
>   to SP4 and it will be resolved.    I had the same problem, so I opened
>   a case with SAP Support about it and IPS SP5 does not support IS SP3
>   until Patch 2.   For more information, see SAP Note 1740516 for the
>   matrix.